# How to resize table cell TD using Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As i have done some research to resize the table cell using jquery ui resize event that has been achieved but this sample had done with TD id. But when i add more TD element in the table it doesn't work. I know that this code is static, so  how to make dynamically ? Thanks in Advance 
[Fiddle] https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/xmf7L8gu/5/

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="v1">View 1</td>

      <td id="v2">View 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">View 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

 $(window).on("load resize", function() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var v1Width = $("#v1").width()


  $("#v1").resizable({
    minWidth: 50,
    maxWidth: windowWidth - 80,
    maxHeight: windowHeight * (.83),
    handles: "e, s"
  }).on("resize", function() {

    if (v1Width == $("#v1").width()) {
      $("#v2").height(0)
    }
    v1Width = $("#v1").width()
  });

  $("#v2").resizable({
    maxHeight: windowHeight * (.83),
    handles: "s"
  }).on("resize", function() {
    $("#v1").height(0)
  });

});
```

Comment: `"But when i add more TD element in the table it doesn't work"` - can you update your post to show the code you've tried?

Comment: you can check the fiddle